# How to output string to multiple files

Tags: c#, .net

I'm inputting master_email_list.txt that only has an email address per line into string fileContent

My form asks how many emails per file and is splitNum
`int splitNum = int.Parse(numToSplit.Text);`

it also asks for the directory saveFolder from folderBroswerDialog1.

I'd like to take the string fineContent and output splitNum emails per file to saveFolder

So it will split fileContent to say 100 emails per file and just auto generate the file names 001.txt 002.txt etc in the saveFolder. The last file would just have the left over.

I was going the direction of if loops, (maybe best way?) what would be the best way of doing this?

### Edit

Here is my new code:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public string startfiledir { get; private set; }
    public string[] fileContent { get; private set; }
    public string saveFolder { get; private set; }
    public string filePath { get; private set; }

    public string writers { get; private set; }

    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            this.button1.Enabled = false;
            Refresh();

            openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = startfiledir;
            openFileDialog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt";
            openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
            openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

            openFileDialog.ShowDialog();

            //Get the path of specified file
            filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;        

            string[] fileContent = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

            //show the button again
            this.button1.Enabled = Enabled;
            Refresh();   
    }

    private void SplitDatabutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            //float splitNum = Int32.Parse(numToSplit.Text);
            float splitNum = 100000;

            ConcurrentDictionary<string, StreamWriter> writers = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, StreamWriter>();

            var Tasks = System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(0, fileContent.Length, (i) =>
            {
                string MyFile = Path.Combine(saveFolder, ((int)(i / ((float)splitNum))).ToString("0000") + ".txt");
                writers.GetOrAdd(MyFile, File.AppendText(MyFile)).WriteLine(fileContent[i]);
            });

            foreach (var writer in writers)
            {
                writer.Value.Close();
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I absolutely would, but I was going to attempt some sort of if loop, but I'm not sure exactly how it would be done or if if loops would even be the way to go. How do you write out 100 lines to a file, then move to the next, etc. It's a little beyond me, i am hoping someone would show the proper way of doing it, and I'll learn from that. I've spent two days searching for an answer. If someone has a link that does this sort of thing would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case is a good candidate for parallel processing. Here is a rough idea of how you can do this job using `System.Tasks`:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string, StreamWriter> writers = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, StreamWriter>();
string[] fileContent = File.ReadAllLines("MAIN_FILE_PATH");

var Tasks = System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(0, fileContent.Length, (i) =>
{
  string MyFile = ((int)(i / 100f)).ToString("0000") + ".txt";
  writers.GetOrAdd(MyFile, File.AppendText(MyFile)).WriteLine(fileContent[i]);
});

foreach (var writer in writers)
  writer.Value.Close();
```

### Edit

Answering your questions in the comment, change the following in this code:

1. Looks like you've used `File.ReadAllText()` to read your master file. Since your master file have got one email per line, I'd suggest you to instead use `ReadAllLines()` so that you don't have to split `fileContent` later. So replace your `ReadAllText()` line with the following line:

   ```
   string[] fileContent = File.ReadAllLines("MAIN_FILE_PATH");
   ```

   The above line will also give you correct count of the number of emails in the master file.
2. Use `saveFolder` and `numToSplit` in the following line to construct your output path:

   ```
   string MyFile = Path.Combine(saveFolder, ((int)(i / ((float)numToSplit))).ToString("0000") + ".txt");
   ```

   This will correctly name chunk files up to 10000 files. If you need more than that, you can increase the number of zeros in `ToString("0000")` part.

### Edit 2

Here are the changes you need to make:

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.IO;

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
  public string startfiledir { get; private set; }
  public string[] fileContent { get; private set; }
  public string saveFolder { get; private set; }
  public string filePath { get; private set; }

  private ConcurrentDictionary<string, StreamWriter> writers = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, StreamWriter>();

  OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

  private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

    this.button1.Enabled = false;
    Refresh();

    openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = startfiledir;
    openFileDialog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt";
    openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
    openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

    openFileDialog.ShowDialog();

    //Get the path of specified file
    filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;

    fileContent = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

    //show the button again
    this.button1.Enabled = Enabled;
    Refresh();
  }

  private void SplitDatabutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    int splitNum = 100;
    int chunks = (int)(fileContent.Length / (float)splitNum);

    var Tasks = Parallel.For(0, chunks, (i) =>
    {
      string MyFile = Path.Combine(savePath, i.ToString("0000") + ".txt");
      using (var W = File.AppendText(MyFile))
      {
        for (int j = i * splitNum; j < (i + 1) * splitNum; j++)
          W.WriteLine(fileContent[j]);
      }       
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Like this idea, you had me at "parallel". what would need to change see following: 

fileContent is already a loaded string from an openfiledialog. I display it's count and filesize, before hand  So I don't need to load the file again what changes would I make considering this. I have a button (button3) to start the split process

2) saveFolder is the string variable for the directory to save the splits in, where would I include this?

3) numToSplit is a variable for how many emails (lines) to put in each file, where do I incorporate this?

Comment: I don't know if this makes a difference `using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
                    {
                        fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();`

But that's how fileContent is being created. should I change how this is done? @dotNET

Comment: @bbrain: Yes. Remove the `using` and `ReadToEnd()` lines and replace them with the `ReadAllLines()` I mentioned above.

Comment: thank you, I have 'ConcurrentDictionary<string, StreamWriter> writers = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, StreamWriter>();' in Button1_click it does the openfiledialog there when you click button1, but in button 3 (SplitDatabutton_Click) is where I have the var tasks = system thre... part. the `writers` come up "does not exist in current context" can't figure out how to get the writers to connect @dotNET

Comment: @bbrain: When you need to access a variable in more than one function, you declare it at class-level; i.e. just outside any function body. Then it will be available in all functions of that class.

Comment: What do I declare `writers` as? If I declare public string writers at Form2 class level,  then I get err cd1061, GetOrAdd string could not be found, missing a using directive or an assembly ref.

Comment: @bbrain: You declare it exactly as I have declared it in the above code. Just move the line `ConcurrentDictionary<string, StreamWriter>...` to class-level.

Comment: Now i get
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: @bbrain: Man, it shouldn't have been this much difficult. Please post your entire code as it currently is for me to see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: sorry to be a PITA, I'm so rusty I posted an edit (can remove) I've not worked with the streamwriter stuff much. Thank you very much for your help. That edit is the "short version" so you see what i'm doing with the 2 buttons..

Comment: @bbrain: The problems you are facing have got nothing to do with `StreamWriter`. These are basic things like variable scope and lifetime, instantiation etc. Also for future reference, if you need to share any new information, you post it in your question, not in other people's answer. I have moved your code to the question section. My corrections are in the second edit section of my answer.

Comment: Sorry, learning "the way" here
Ok, made those changes, now it runs, makes some files
0000.txt sometimes in order on a 4m record file, then sometimes out of order on a 36M record file like 0000.txt,  0018.txt 0036.txt, etc but they have nothing in them and it throws Exception unhandled
`System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred.'`
`IOException: The process cannot access the file 'D:\data\Splits\0006.txt' because it is being used by another process.`

Also do you have a paypal I could send a tip too? I'd like to send you a tip for helping me with this...

Comment: IOException: The process cannot access the file 'D:\data\Splits\0002.txt' because it is being used by another process.

It made empty files 0000.txt, 0002.txt, 0004.txt, 0006.txt, then threw the error.

Comment: To get working: Added "using System.Threading.Tasks;" and changed savePath to saveFolder and it worked. It chopped up a 4m record file in 100 line files (44,702 files) in a few seconds as fast as my NVMe drive could write them. absolutely amazing!

Comment: i'd like to send you a tip, and chat about other projects paid of course. Could you give a way to contact?

Comment: @bbrain: Good to know that you finally succeeded. For contact, leave your email/skype id here and I'll ping me when i get a chance.

Comment: @ dotNET hit me up, skype  neosinn

Answer (score 0):

You need to begin by spliting up the tasks you want to accomplish. The first step after you have read the file contends would be split the string to collection of emails

```
var fileContent = File.ReadAllText(sourceFileName);
var emails = fileContent.Split(new string[]{Environment.NewLine},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

As described in OP, the emails are organized one per line. Hence you could use NewLine character for splitting the string. The next step would be to group the emails in to sub collections based on the split number (emails per file).

```
var emailCollection = emails.Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
        .GroupBy(x => x.Index / emailsPerFile)
        .Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Value).ToList())
        .ToList();
```

Finally, you need to write the file. You could now loop the emailCollections (which is already split based on emails per file) and write the collections to a file. You can use string.Join to concatenate the emails back as a single string and use File.WriteAllText to write to the file.

```
var counter = 1;
foreach(var item in emailCollection)
{
    var contends = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,item);
    File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(destinationFolder,$"{destinationFileSuffix}{counter++}.txt"),contends);
}
```

Comment: I got this to work pretty well. I made a few changes to the variables. I didn't need the var fileContent part as fileContent is already created, only had to do  `var splitNum = Int32.Parse(numToSplit.Text);` and change destinationFolder to saveFolder. That said, when working with large files, i had to add `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true"` as a runtime so it would do larger files. Very large files, example a 0.8GB file will use up to 16GB of memory in splitting files. It's fast, but uses a lot of memory. But this does in fact work pretty good as long as you have a lot of system memory